# using regex to find everything inbetween

Tags: regex

Using a regular expression, how can I find everything in between `<p` and `</A>` and replace it with just `<p>` in the following string. (The contents between `<p </A>` is never the same, so I just need to get everything and delete it).

```
 <p TITLE="Super Sent., lib. 3 d. 6 q. 1 a. 2 arg. 3"><A NAME="8220"><SPAN CLASS="ref">[8220] Super Sent., lib. 3 d. 6 q. 1 a. 2 arg. 3 </SPAN></A>
```

In short I want to replace all instances of the above with just: `<p>`

Comment: What is expected output exactly? Please add it to your question

Comment: That's a really simple pattern, so it's not clear which part of it you are having trouble with.  What specifically is the question?

Comment: Regex is not a good [tool for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: *how can I find everything in between `<p` and `</A>` and replace it with just `<p>`*, Then expected result is this `<p<p></A>` ? I hardly think so ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get you right or not, but I guess you need something like this:

```
(<p).*?(<\/A>)
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lW9qD1/1)